# В каком варианте ответа на месте пропуска в окончании пишется Е?

Tags: правописание

Запуталась! В каком варианте ответа на месте пропуска в окончании пишется Е:

1. В Карели?
2. В Якути?
3. Пприток Би?

Знаю ,что пишется И, но ведь существительные 1 склонения в Предложном падеже имеют окончание Е? Спасибо.

Comment: @СЕТЛАНА, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Ни в одном из перечисленных вариантов в окончании не пишется Е.
В Карели**и**, в Якути**и**, приток Би**и**.

Answer (score 1):

Существительные на -ия(армия) в дательном и предложном падеже, в отличии от других существительных женского рода 1-го склонения, имеют окончание -и( кому?- армии; о ком? -об армии).